# Css media query for Chrome and excluding Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, sass, media-queries

I'm developing a web app using Firefox as main browser due to client pre-requisites.
I'm facing some minor issues regarding media queries for isolating the css for only Chrome, however I need excluding Firefox. The following media query works for both Chrome and Firefox:

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {...}`

and this only on Firefox:

`@-moz-document url-prefix() {...}`

However I'm not being able to merge those queries to isolate Firefox and achieve only Chrome.
How can get this result? I do appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find any way to solve the current problem, then I've chosen target the Google Chrome as main browser and use the Mozilla Firefox media query to fix some minor design issues.

`@-moz-document url-prefix() {...}`